# get data from API CORS

Tags: json, ajax, api, cors, jsonp

I'm trying to get a json data from a server that doesn't support CORS. I read the Jsonp is the solution for that kind of stituation but i still can't make it work  : 
My code :

```
 var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'token',
  'Accept': 'application/json'
};
function myCallbackFunction(data){
            $('body').text(data.response);
        }
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
     headers : headers,
     url: "https://site/api/etc",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){console.log(data);},
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback : "myCallbackFunction",
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

i get this

> error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

i know that's because the server returns a json data but i don't know how to correct that because if change data type to json i get a CORS related error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://site/api/1.0/etc. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://site' is therefore not allowed access.

that means CORS not supported in the server side 
but i use postman it works i don't understand.
i've tried a lot of other thing but could get the data .
Please help .
Thank you.
PS : i'm under a tomcat server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just put what worked for me here :
So what i did is create a rest controller using "okhttp" instead of an ajax call this way there won't be a context creating the problem then retreive the data and manipulate it with js .